# How to save my image data to a specific formats when developing a Maya Plugin?

Tags: image, maya

I'm writing a plug-in for Maya by which I want to let user render the scene by some algorithms and output some maps(diffuse map, normal map and light map) to a specific file in a specific format. Of course, I've done generating the related texture data in the algorithms, but now I'm stuck on how to turn them into images. I need my image data support PNG, OpenEXR, DDS, and TGA. What I know for now is that there is a API Class `MImage` which could do the similar task, yet none of above is supported except TGA.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you make your own renderer than its up to you to dump the image buffer. Mainly because it also affects how your core functionality works from a caching perceptive, that's how all the external renders in Maya do it. Off course you might want to use MImage if you really want to limit your market and your renders functionality. (for example since the renderer is yours you have a unlimited license pool bvut ultimately if your rendering is tightly tied to Maya your license pool is limited.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks joojaa. After some delving I found actually MImage does support most LDR formats, such as png, dds, tga and tif. But it still got no way to handle openEXR. So for exr I decide to customize my implementations. Indeed I shouldn't rely on MImage too much !